# Can I force the archiving of Nlog files

Tags: nlog

I've made a page in my website where the admin can see all the errorfiles.
I've set the archiving to '`day`', so for every day where an error occured I have a file called `error.yyyyMMdd.txt` (in a subfolder called `archives`) and for today I have the file '`error.txt`'

What happens is that when I have a few days without errors, the file '`error.txt`' is not touched, so the file '`errors.txt`' is not from today, but from lets say 5 days ago, and in the archives subfolder, I don't have an error file for the situation five days ago.

Is there a way to 'force' Nlog to perform it's archiving and thereby create the archive file?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible (yet).

If this will be added, it will be added as an [method on the `FileTarget` class](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/Methods_T_NLog_Targets_FileTarget.htm)